# Notepad++ auto completion does not work

Tags: notepad++

My Notepad++ autocompletion does not work properly.

I set `Preferences > Auto-completion > HTML tags` to be checked.

But nothing happens.  After I typed both tags, say `<h1></h1>`, the color
turns to purple.  However, the second `</h1>` does not come up *automatically*.

Can anyone help fix this?

Comment: is the document name with a .htm/html extension? if not, have you set the files langague type in the Langague menu?

Answer (score 2):

By default notepad++ and similar text editors autocomplete text using already entered earlier substrings. So next time you type your html tag there would be tooltip with autocompletion options. However you can enable expected behaviour by "teaching" notepad++ doing it.

Notepad++ wiki has article on [autocompletion.](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Auto_Completion)

Comment: location of autocompletion article is now here: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/auto-completion/

Answer (score 1):

My Eureka Moment when
I tried the following steps.
Settings>Preferences>AutoCompletion> Check/Tick XML/HTML tags >Close.
Next.
Languages>H>HTML

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I fixed the problem by discarding some plugins.  It seems "TextFx Character" plugins conflicts with autocomplete, as it works after disabling it.

Don't know why...

Comment: I removed the "Emmet" plugin and Autocompletion is working again. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple steps to get auto-completion to work - one was the Settings > Preferences > Auto-completion and click Enable auto-Completion and subsequently click the html/xml close tag (step 4):

[image]

Comment: Not a great answer but thumbs up for the nice screenshot.